# Deployment server uses "application/x-octet-stream"

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, mime-types, velocity

While deploying a Spring-MVC application to a Tomcat server, I ran into a problem: The server keeps using `application/x-octet-stream` as a response type. Thus, the browser doesn't display the page but instead offers to download it.

The website worked as expected on a local Tomcat server - maybe that one has a different default setting?

The URL looks similar to the following one: http://www.example.org/mysite/search

My web.xml (partially):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the servlet-context.xml:

```
<beans:bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="cache" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="velocityConfig"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
</beans:bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example.website" />
```

How can I change the default MIME type to `text/html` in my project so that it works on all servers without additional configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling [VelocityLayoutViewResolver.setContentType](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29) when configuring your `viewResolver` bean:

```
    <beans:property name="contentType" value="text/html" />
```

Comment: Strange - on my local development server, this property allows me to change the type. However, the deployment server seems to ignore this property and continues serving the pages as "application/x-octet-stream"...